# Cronjob not working - meant to post tot Twitter

Tags: raspbian, ssh, cron

I'm trying to get my Pi to post the amount of used RAM to Twitter.

I'm using a script I modified myself from [here](http://www.sbprojects.com/projects/raspberrypi/tweet.php), although I'm not very proficient in bash..

This is the file, it is located in /home/pi/bin/memtweet;

```
#! /bin/bash

# Configuration variables
TWIT_USER="USERNAME"
TWIT_SECRET="SUPERTWEET_PASS"

# Other variables
TWIT_URL="http://api.supertweet.net/1/statuses/update.xml"
TWEET=$(free -m | awk '/^Mem:/  { printf( "%s\n", $3 ); }')
curl -u $TWIT_USER:$TWIT_SECRET -d "status=RAM USAGE: $TWEET MB" $TWIT_URL -s > /dev/null
```

I'm using SuperTweet (as you can see) and echoing the amount of RAM, actually works.

I've use crontab -e to try and run it every 5 minutes (although I'll change it to hourly, I just wanted to see if it could work).

```
5 * * * * /home/pi/bin/memtweet
```

I've tried setting the cron for both root and the user, pi, but neither of them work.

Here's the last cron error I received when I was attempting to run the script through the pi user;

```
/bin/sh: 1: pi: not found
```

If anyone has an ideas as to how I could make this work, I would be very grateful!

**EDIT: It looks like it could be the bash script, I've tried running it a few times and it doesn't seem to be posting to Twitter.**

Comment: Build it up slowly. Does the `curl` command work on the command line?

Comment: Yes, it does. I've isolated the problem, I'm now using a different piece of code, still bash, and the cronjob still doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Your crontab entry says to run the job on the fifth minute of every hour. To run it every five minutes: `*/5 * * * * /home/pi/bin/memtweet`

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working..

Comment: Here's the out put from /var/log/syslog, it looks like it worked but maybe the script didn't? [http://pastebin.com/GmF2bhcs](http://pastebin.com/GmF2bhcs)

Comment: I got it working, thank you! It seems it was to do with the permissions.

Comment: @Hugo Can you post the solution for future reference?

Comment: @Hugo crontab file must not be writable or executable by other than the file's owner.  Was that the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the script! Works like a charm. Just make sure you don't add/create it as sudo. :-/

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit farcical, but use `#!/bin/bash` and not `#! /bin/bash`. I think it doesn't recognize the correct shell.

Comment: The space is optional and accepted.

Comment: oh is it? never saw it with a space.

Comment: The first two bullet points under [Selected issues](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#details).